# Can't compare serial data in the Handle Method

Tags: android, serial-port

I'm making an alarm system based on a serial connection data. I'm showing the data in a TextView. In addition I want to activate the `alarm` and `sendSMS` methods if the data reaches 20. This is the code in the `Handle` method:

```
case MESSAGE_READ:
    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;              

    // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

    mTextView.setText(readMessage);
    if (readMessage.equals(20))
    {
        alarm();
        sendSMS();
    }
    break;
```

When the `TextView` shows 20, the application just won't call the `alarm` and `sendSMS` methods. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are comparing a String with an int, try this

```
readMessage.equals("20")
```

Comment: Provide more data with your question. What do you mean by **serial connection data**?

Comment: It's a serial bluetooth connection. my application is connected with it. The data i receive is an upcounter from 0 to 30. Now if my application receive "20", i want to call alarm() and sendSMS(). The textView shows the upcounter but when it turn "20", stil not calling those two methods..:(

Comment: What are you doing in **alarm()**? How do you know it is not being called? Try to print messages to LogCat?